# setting up an IRC server on freebsd

Tags: freebsd, port-forwarding, irc

[ssh port forward to access my home machine from anywhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19620/ssh-port-forward-to-access-my-home-machine-from-anywhere)

In continuation to what I've been trying to do, I want to setup an `IRC` chat server on my freebsd box at home so friends can join that server and we can chat.

I believe, I need to run IRC server on a port and advertise/forward/expose that port to outside world. - this is my understanding. Please correct me if I am wrong.

How can I do that?

Comment: I ended up with UnrealIRCd on my freebsd box and forwarded 6667 port. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct- you will need to forward the port running your IRC daemon ( usually something like 6667 ).  Just log into your router, forward the port to your IRC server, and you should be good to go!  Then you'll just give your friends your external IP address.

Comment: What is a good server for freebsd? if you know?

Comment: I installed unrealircd via sysinstall. Where can I find the config files?

Comment: @hari ! Don't just ask anything that comes to your mind - first **show some effort** in finding it out yourself. Otherwise you'll annoy people and get bad reputation.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: I am a newbie and doing my due diligence to find things around. I sincerely try my best to do my homework before asking. Here the relevant que: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19653/freebsd-installed-package-location

Comment: Ah, now that is something different from the form in the above comment :) I see I even upvoted it lately. BTW, I'm waiting for you on the [chat about your previous problem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1219/discussion-between-rozcietrzewiacz-and-hari).

Comment: Thanks for your help @rozcietrzewiacz. I am away from where my box is, so when I get on it, I will give you a holler. :)