# FreeBSD installed package location

Tags: package-management, freebsd

I installed `Unrealircd` on FreeBSD via the `sysinstall` utility.

I cannot seem to find the location where it was installed.

How can I find the default location of installed packages?

**Edit:** I found the package with the `find` utility. But in general, how do I know where `sysinstall` would put the package after installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this information in /var/db/pkg/PKG_NAME/+CONTENTS:

```
/var/db/pkg/wget-1.12_2# head +CONTENTS 
@comment PKG_FORMAT_REVISION:1.1
@name wget-1.12_2
@comment ORIGIN:ftp/wget
@cwd /usr/local
@pkgdep libiconv-1.13.1_1
@comment DEPORIGIN:converters/libiconv
@pkgdep gettext-0.18.1.1
@comment DEPORIGIN:devel/gettext
man/man1/wget.1.gz
```

This is effectively the same as rpm -ql 'RPM_NAME' on linux

Answer (score 5):

To find the package a file belongs to you can use the following command:

```
pkg_info -W /full/path/to/file
```

To see the list of files a package installed:

```
pkg_info -L packagename
```