# Set some firewall ports to only accept local network connections?

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall

How do I set up the firewall on a system in a LAN so that some ports are only open to connections from the local area network, and not from the outside world?

For example, I have a box running [Scientific Linux 6.1](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=scientific) (a RHEL based distro), and I want its SSH server to only accept connections from localhost or LAN. How do I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With the kernel's [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) completely empty (`iptables -F`), this will do what you ask:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

This says that all LAN addresses are allowed to talk to TCP port 22, that localhost gets the same consideration (yes, 127.* not just 127.0.0.1), and packets from every other address not matching those first two rules get unceremoniously dropped into the [bit bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_bucket). You can use `REJECT` instead of `DROP` if you want an active rejection (TCP RST) instead of making TCP port 22 a black hole for packets.

If your LAN doesn't use the 192.168.0.* block, you will naturally need to change the IP and mask on the first line to match your LAN's IP scheme.

These commands may not do what you want if your firewall already has some rules configured. (Say `iptables -L` as root to find out.) What frequently happens is that one of the existing rules grabs the packets you're trying to filter, so that appending new rules has no effect. While you can use `-I` instead of `-A` with the `iptables` command to splice new rules into the middle of a chain instead of appending them, it's usually better to find out how the chains get populated on system boot and modify that process so your new rules always get installed in the correct order.

### RHEL 7+

On recent RHEL type systems, the best way to do that is to use [`firewall-cmd`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_firewalld.html) or its GUI equivalent. This tells the OS's `firewalld` daemon what you want, which is what actually populates and manipulates what you see via `iptables -L`.

### RHEL 6 and Earlier

On older RHEL type systems, the easiest way to modify firewall chains when ordering matters is to edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. The OS's GUI and TUI firewall tools are rather simplistic, so once you start adding more complex rules like this, it's better to go back to good old config files. Beware, once you start doing this, you risk losing your changes if you ever use the OS's firewall tools to modify the configuration, since it may not know how to deal with handcrafted rules like these.

Add something like this to that file:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Where you add it is the tricky bit. If you find a line in that file talking about `--dport 22`, simply replace it with the three lines above. Otherwise, it should probably go before the first existing line ending in `-j ACCEPT`. Generally, you'll need to acquire some familiarity with the way [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) works, at which point the correct insertion point will be obvious.

Save that file, then say `service iptables restart` to reload the firewall rules. Be sure to do this while logged into the console, in case you fat-finger the edits! You don't want to lock yourself out of your machine while logged in over SSH.

The similarity to the commands above is no coincidence. Most of this file consists of arguments to the `iptables` command. The differences relative to the above are that the `iptables` command is dropped and the `INPUT` chain name becomes the special RHEL-specific `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain. (If you care to examine the file in more detail, you'll see earlier in the file where they've essentially renamed the `INPUT` chain. Why? Couldn't say.)

Answer (score 5):

The low-level tool for firewall setup under Linux is [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables). There are also higher-level tools available. I don't know if Scientific Linux has a recommended firewall tool.

According to [this web page](http://www.helpwithit.net/book/export/html/28) (I haven't verified that it applies to 6.1), `service iptables save` will save the current firewall rules, and these saved rules are loaded at boot time. So you need to set up the rules you want through `iptables` commands (or any other means), then run `service iptables save` to make your setup persistent.

[Scott Pack's blog post](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/base-rulesets-in-iptables/) is a start for dropping “oddball” packets that aren't usually needed and have a high risk of being part of an attack. Beyond that, you'll want to close all incoming ports, and open only the ones you need. Something like this:

```
# Accept everything on the loopback interface
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# Accept ICMP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
# Drop oddball packets
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -f -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
# Accept packets that are part of established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Accept selected incoming connections, e.g. ssh from 10.0.42.x
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 10.0.42.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# Reject incoming connections that aren't explicitly accepted
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Comment: Gilles, didn't you misread the question a little bit? I understand that the Scientific Linux box is one of the computers on LAN, but not the firewall.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, the box is one of the computers on the LAN.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz I understand that the firewall is on the same machine as the server. I agree that the question is ambiguous to some extent, but since penyuan only mentioned the OS of one machine, I presume everything is happening on that machine. Otherwise this wouldn't be a unix question, this would be an underspecified network admin question.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to do it is with `iptables`. It looks as though that's been adequately covered by others, so, just for completeness, I'll point out an alternative access control method that is available for many daemons on most Linux distros. That access control method is provided by the `libwrap` library.

To check whether your favourite daemon has `libwrap` support, try running the following:

```
ldd `which sshd` | grep libwrap
```

If you get a non-empty result, such as

```
libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f84e7b0e000)
```

then you are definitely good to go.

It's almost a certainty that your `sshd` daemon does have `libwrap` support, and so it should consult the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files for access control. Assuming your local LAN network is `192.168.100.0/24`, you can **deny** access to `sshd` to all clients **except** those on the local host or on the local LAN by putting the following into your `/etc/hosts.deny` file:

```
sshd: ALL EXCEPT 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0, [::1]/128, 192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0
```

Note that this method **does not** actually open or close ports, per se. It simply tells daemons that use this method of access control whether to accept or reject connection attempts from clients that match the given pattern(s).

For complete details, check out the man pages, starting with `hosts_access(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own linux-based firewall, you'd best setup `iptables`, as others describe here. If not and the firewall is your router, then most probably the default configuration already prevents access from outside, unless you explicitly enable port forwarding (as I recently described in answer [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19620/ssh-port-forward-to-access-my-home-machine-from-anywhere)).

For additional security above that, you can use a separate subnet for in-LAN connections. To do so, for each computer add a second IP address that would be used only within LAN and not by the router. Let's say the whole LAN is now using `192.168.0.xxx` addresses and the router (gateway, firewall) is `192.168.0.1`. So add a second address for each computer - for example:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.5.1/24
```

Next, edit `sshd` configuration to use only this address (so that it would not allow connections coming on `192.168.0.xxx`) - edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and modify `ListenAddress` to the one of your new subnet (`192.168.5.1` in the above example). That's it! If you do not configure the gateway to route that subnet's communication, it should be separated from the outside.