# Will this open up a non-standard port to ssh?

Tags: networking, iptables

I am following tutorials on iptable and want to allow ssh traffic on my non-standard SSH port = YYY. I think this is how you do it, but want to double check so I don't lock myself out of my server. This will add a rule as part of an "input chain" (I'm not sure what that is). The rule will accept ssh traffic on port=YYY (by allowing tcp traffic on port=YYY). Right?

```
$sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport YYY -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is the ssh server listening that port?

Comment: @Braiam yes it is

Comment: Instead of using iptables, I just modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which is much simpler. ==EDIT== hang on, perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Sparhawk That does different things. `sshd_config` is where you tell SSH to listen on a different port. You also need to tell your firewall not to block that port, which is what this question is about

Comment: @Gilles Ah okay, thanks. I use ufw anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This rule in itself won't lock you out since it only causes some traffic to be accepted.

It is the right rule to allow traffic to port YYY. Make sure that there isn't an earlier rule that would block all traffic (rules are processed in order, the first match applies). Run `iptables -nvL INPUT` to list the input rules. `INPUT` is the name of the chain (i.e. a list of rules) that is applied to incoming packets.

You'll presumably a REJECT rule coming **after** this one to reject other incoming traffic. This is where you need to be careful. [Set some firewall ports to only accept local network connections?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19791/set-some-firewall-ports-to-only-accept-local-network-connections/19800#19800) contains an example of a firewall setting that should be suitable (but use at your own risk, I won't go and reset your server if you get locked out).

Make sure that you don't block output from the server; for a simple configuration, just leave output unrestricted.

To avoid getting locked out, a trick is to put a command to reset the firewall to wide open on a timer, e.g.

```
sleep 300; iptables -I INPUT -j accept
```

I recommend doing this from inside screen or tmux. If you do that directly from the ssh connection, there's a risk that the command you run will try to output something and fail because its terminal isn't available anymore.

Note that there is no security benefit in putting SSH on a non-standard port: it won't make SSH less prone to attacks. The only advantage is that you'll have fewer scanning attacks, so less flooding of your logs.

Comment: I would note that you can verify the rule is matching before blocking by checking to see if the match counter increases (first column of `iptables -nvL`)