# Unable to SSH into Puppy Linux, even though SSHD is running

Tags: ssh, firewall, sshd

I installed OpenSSH client and server on my Puppy Linux computer. That computer is behind a router. I tried to `ssh` into it over the internet (outside the router) but it times out. Also doesn't work if I try to `ssh` from the computer itself. `telnet` didn't work either, but I can successfully ping the computer.

```
sh-4.1# ssh [ip address]
```

hangs for a minute, then shows:

```
sh-4.1# ssh: connect to host [ip address] port 22: Connection timed out
```

I know `sshd` is running:

```
sh-4.1# ps | grep -i sshd
sh-4.1# 24312 root      0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
```

The firewall icon on the taskbar in Puppy says "Firewall OFF".

How do I check if ports are in use or blocked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug SSH port forwarding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20086/how-to-debug-ssh-port-forwarding)

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules active?  Try `iptables -vnL`, this will show you the active filtering rules.  You problem sounds like something is dropping your inbound packets.